# How to do GLMM if the dependent variable is categorical in R?

Tags: glmm, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to run a logistic regression on categorical dependent variables data; The dependent variable is a choice of Yes/No/Unsure.

I want to use `glmer` in `lme4`, how do I specify the family type?

If I transformed the dependent variables into rate of Yes (`ACC`), the distribution of `ACC` look like the histogram below. Can I use the following formula to fit the model?

```
model <- lmer(ACC ~ group * tone * focus + (1|subject/word), data = d)
```

Fixed effects: `group`, `tone`, `focus`

Random effects: `subject`, `word`

[image]

Comment: You can collapse as Mark suggested, but probably more straightforward to run an ordinal regression, e.g. clmm from package ordinal

Comment: Thank you very much. I found an excellent book introducing this problem[Summary and Analysis of Extension Program Evaluation in R](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/E_01.html) according to your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to conduct a multinomial logistic regression using the `lme4` package. [I have this post from SO saved for when I am in the situation you are in.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082396/multinomial-logistic-multilevel-models-in-r) If I am wrong, I would love for someone to correct me, because I would like to use that functionality.

When I have 3 levels of a categorical dependent variable, I have fit three separate models before:

- DV in first model: Level 1 or Levels 2 and 3
- DV in second model: Level 2 or Levels 1 and 3
- DV in third model: Level 3 or Level 1 and 2

It seems like you are OK with collapsing across Levels 2 and 3 (No and Unsure). So what I would do is recode your dependent variable to be dichotomous:

```
d$newDV <- as.factor(ifelse(d$oldDV=="Yes", 1, 0))
```

Then you could run a model like:

```
model <- glmer(newDV ~ group * tone * focus + (1|subject/word), 
               data = d, family=binomial)
```

Keep in mind, though, that you will want to likely include random slopes for `group`, `tone`, and `focus` (or at least test to see if they are significant). The code would look something like this, *but only if all of the three predictors are at the lowest level in the multilevel structure of the data*:

`(1+group+tone+focus|subject/word)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit and answer and it's very helpful. I still have two questions. (1) Sometimes the 'Unsure' choice is important for the research so we can't collapse it. How to deal with this situation. (2) I think this formula is excellent `(1+tone+focus|subject/word)`, but I find error 'Error in calculation of the Satterthwaite's approximation. The output of lme4 package is returned anova from lme4 is returned some computational error has occurred in lmerTest' with it. It is strange that `(1+focus+tone|subject/word)` is OK. I am very confused about it.

Comment: I would have to see the data to be certain what is happening, but you can find more information on the `lme4` syntax here: http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer